# MySQL console slow on import of huge SQL files

Tags: mysql, sql, console, wamp

My import of SQL via the MySQL console is rather slow, and, as our SQL file is increasing every day, I would like to know if there are any alternatives on how to import an SQL file faster.

Changing to Oracle or other systems is not an option, the configuration has to stay the same.

Currently the SQL file is: 1.5 GB.
I'm on [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) with Apache 2.2.14, PHP 5.2.11 and MySQL 5.1.41.

Perhaps the issue is here, import is done by a simple:

```
mysql -u username -p dbname < sqlfilename.sql
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using mysqlimport or LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: This is something that has to be placed in the Sql if I'm correct, that is not possible, as you cannot change a Sql file that is 1.4 Gb in any editor, and it is coming from external source.

Comment: It May Help someone: First restart your computer, then disable your antivirus/firewalls/bandwidth trackers + any other programs you dont need running. But disabling those two things I increased speed like 6x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having indexes enabled during import will slow your server down to a crawl. `ALTER TABLE`tablename`DISABLE KEYS`; and using `..ENABLE KEYS` prior to and after import, will improve import speed, but will take some time to re-create indexes, so it might not be a big speed gain after all.

Also, perhaps using myisam tables (in contrast to innodb with referential integrity options) usually gives better performance, as there is no referential integrity overhead involved.

Personally, I don't use import statement from mysql console, but import sql files using `mysql -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME < file.sql`, and it works well for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Consider using mysqlimport command. It will take flat file that contains data in some tab-or-something-else separated format, and import it directly into table, faster than executing sql queries.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html for info on mysqlimport command, if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: By default, when exporting tables MySQL Workbench surrounds `INSERT` statements for each table by `DISABLE KEYS; ...; ENABLE KEYS`.

Answer (score 8):

Try these http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

It's maybe an autocommit issue, turn that off then see what happends.

```
SET autocommit=0 ; source <your dump file> ; COMMIT ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Switching autocommit off is the first of a series of recommendations given in [Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) to speed up restore operations for MySQL.

Instead of switching autocommit off manually at restore time you can already dump your MySQL data in a way that includes all necessary statements right into your SQL file.

The command line parameter for mysqldump is `--no-autocommit`. You might also consider to add `--opt` which sets a combination of other parameters to speed up restore operations.

Here is an example for a complete mysqldump command line as I use it, containing `--no-autocommit` and `--opt`:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uMyUser -p'MyPassword' --no-autocommit --opt --default-character-set=utf8 --quote-names  MyDbName  >  dump.sql
```

For details of these parameters see the [reference of mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, becuase I'm not sure where the bottleneck is... However, I've have been really impressed with the free [Toad for MySQL](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-mysql/default.aspx) tool as a replacement MySQL management console.  It's got great import tools, and is generally miles better IMO than the standard MySQL management console.

Comment: any one else has experience with Toad on this issue with huge datafiles?

Answer (score 0):

Following works on a slow POS device to save 90% time:

When the .sql file has one insert statement per line,this takes 1-30 msec. When I put 500 commands in one sql statement separated with semicolons ; then it takes a second.
Disadvantage is that the sql is not really readable anymore, since every line is 20000 characters or more.

With mysqldump you can create a file without the linefeeds.