# Why is import of SQL so slow?

Tags: mysql, windows, linux

I have an SQL file containing two tables with around 600,000 rows altogether. Yesterday, I tried to import the file into my MySQL database on Fedora 16, and it took over 2 hours to import the file. On my Windows PC it took 7 minutes. My Linux and Windows machines have exactly the same hardware. A couple of my friends tried it too, and they had a similar experience.

The command we were using was: `mysql -u root database_name < sql_file.sql`.

Why is there such a difference in speed?

Comment: Same table types (INNODB/MYISAM/...)?

Comment: Yeah, the table types are the same: Innodb

Comment: Have you checked out mysqlimport ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956407/mysql-console-slow-on-import-of-huge-sql-files

Comment: @LarsSteen It's hard to judge whether Windows is "too fast" or Fedora "too slow" without knowing the hardware. Is the disk an SSD or a spinning disk for example?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It's a spinning disk. Model: WDC WD5000BEVT-2 5400rpm.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

My bet is that Fedora 16 is honoring the transaction/sync semantics and Windows is not. If you do the math, 600,000 updates in two hours is 5,000 per minute. That's the same order of magnitude as a disk's rotation rate.

You can try adding `SET autocommit=0;` to the beginning of your import file and `COMMIT;` to the end. See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) for more information.

Comment: It made a huge difference! Just tried it again, and the total time for the import was below 3 minutes. Tanks a lot :)

Comment: The difference is astronomical. I've waited 20 minutes on a 27MB dump file before starting over with your suggestion. It took less than a minute afterwards. Great answer!

Comment: This worked well. Otherwise, reshaping the input-file using bulk inserts works as well. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue when adding lots of rows to a join table. The actual DB was only 2.3MB, but was adding 26,163 records. Previously this wasn't even completing. With your suggestion it worked great!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the implications of this? I assume the creators of MySQL didn't put it on slow mode for no reason?

Comment: @Prinsig It only affects cases where power is lost or the system crashes in the middle of the operation. If you're willing to restart the operation with a clean database if this happens, then you can disable these safeties.

Comment: Is there a way to invoke this without editing the import file? My "complete" file is 2.8GB large, and takes forever to import. But seeing how I can't control the contents of the file, I'd have to edit it for every time I wanted to make a change

Comment: Sure, you can use a command line like `(echo "SET autocommit = 0"; cat MyInputFile; echo "COMMIT;" ) | mysql  ...`

Comment: semicolumn after SET autocommit=0;  is omiited . Full command should look like : (echo "SET autocommit = 0; "; cat MyInputFile; echo "COMMIT;" ) | mysql ...

Comment: thanks. my load time of ~1GB dataset went from 17 hours to 9 minutes.

Comment: Didn't speed up performance for me. Without this it was 23 minutes and after it was 23 minutes (3GB .sql file).

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you export .sql file as `BULK INSERT` option and import it, try these options while taking a backup using mysqldump

`--extended-insert`: use multiple-row insert statements

`--quick`: do not do buffering of row data, good if tables are large

**Note:** Make sure you should increase value of `max_allowed_packet`=32M or more in my.cnf file before generating .sql file.

Comment: @LarsSteen Did Mahesh Patil's tip make any difference?

Comment: No.  Didn't make much difference.